# custom Bitcoin Stripe Rails payments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments, bitcoin

I received an email from a customer saying that they never received their product after paying on Bitcoin/Stripe. the trouble is, I couldn't find a way to thoroughly test Bitcoin in a sandbox, so are not sure if my implementation is working as it should be. The sandbox automatically fills the receiver so I get the notification of payment, and all is ok. however when running live, im not sure if my polling is working correctly. I posted all my relevant code below, can anyone see any flaws in the code?

*my Store is running Ruby(2.3.1p112) on Rails (4.2.6)

my payment_bitcoin.html.erb

```
<%= render :partial => "offsite_checkout_summary" %>

<p>Your license key, along with your purchase receipt, will be sent to <strong><%= @order.licensee_name %></strong> at <strong><%= @order.email %></strong> once payment has been confirmed.</p>

<div id="extra_purchase_notes">
    <em><strong>Note:</strong> The bitcoin link and price provided is only valid for <span id="countdown_time">10:00</span> minutes.</em>
</div>

<div class="d cl"></div>
<%= render :partial => "items_checkout_summary", :locals => { order: @order } %>
  <div id="bitcoin_payment_address">
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/stripe.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      Stripe.setPublishableKey('<%= $STRIPE_PREFS['stripe_publishable_key'] %>');
      function populateBitcoinCheckout(status, response) {
        if (status === 200) {
          document.getElementById("bitcoin_total").innerHTML = " (" + response.bitcoin_amount/100000000 + " BTC)";
          document.getElementById("bitcoin_payment_string").innerHTML = 'Please send: <strong>' + response.bitcoin_amount/100000000 + ' BTC</strong> to <strong>' + '<a href="' + response.bitcoin_uri + '&label=Software+Purchase">' + response.inbound_address + '</a></strong>';
          document.getElementById("btc-button").href = response.bitcoin_uri + '&label=Software+Purchase';

                    //poll reciever
                    Stripe.bitcoinReceiver.pollReceiver(response.id, filledReceiverHandler(response));

          //configure timer
          function startTimer(duration, countdown) {
              var timer = duration,minutes,seconds;
              var t = setInterval(function () {
                  minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
                  seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

                  minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
                  seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

                  countdown.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

                  if (--timer < 0) {
                      clearInterval(t);
                      document.getElementById("bitcoin_total").innerHTML = "";
                      document.getElementById("bitcoin_payment_string").innerHTML = "";
                      document.getElementById("bitcoin_button_text").innerHTML = "Refresh Order"
                      document.getElementById("btc-button").href = "javascript:history.back()"
                      document.getElementById("extra_purchase_notes").innerHTML = "<em><strong>Oops...</strong> This order has expired, use the Refresh Order button to retry.</em>"
                      Stripe.bitcoinReceiver.cancelReceiverPoll(response.id);
                  }
              }, 1000);
          }

          //start timer
          var countdown = document.getElementById('countdown_time');
          startTimer(600, countdown);

        } else {
          document.getElementById("bitcoin_uri_string").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response);
          Stripe.bitcoinReceiver.cancelReceiverPoll(response.id);
        }
      }

      Stripe.bitcoinReceiver.createReceiver({
        amount: "<%= (@order.total * 100).round %>",
        currency: 'usd',
        description: 'Software purchase',
        email: "<%= @order.email %>"
      }, populateBitcoinCheckout);

            function filledReceiverHandler(response)
            {
                if (response.filled === true) {
                    function post(path, parameters) {
                var form = $('<form></form>');
                form.attr("method", "post");
                form.attr("action", path);

                $.each(parameters, function(key, value) {
            if ( typeof value == 'object' || typeof value == 'array' ){
                $.each(value, function(subkey, subvalue) {
                    var field = $('<input />');
                    field.attr("type", "hidden");
                    field.attr("name", key+'[]');
                    field.attr("value", subvalue);
                    form.append(field);
                });
            } else {
                var field = $('<input />');
                field.attr("type", "hidden");
                field.attr("name", key);
                field.attr("value", value);
                form.append(field);
            }
            });
            $(document.body).append(form);
            form.submit();
            }
                post('purchase_bitcoin', response);
            }
        }
    </script>
    </div>
</div>
<p id="bitcoin_payment_string"></p>
<div class="d"></div>

<p style="text-align: right;">
  <a id="btc-button"><button class="bitcoin-button" style="visibility: visible;"><span id="bitcoin_button_text">Pay with Bitcoin</span></button></a>
</p>
```

and the relevant controller method:

```
#bitcoin purchase
  def purchase_bitcoin
    require 'stripe'
    if check_if_order_exists() == false
      if session[:failure_reason] != nil
        render :action => 'failed'
        return
      end
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
      return
    end

    if session[:item_number] == nil
      flash[:notice] = 'Nothing to purchase'
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
      return
    end

    #create the order
    generateNewOrder("Bitcoin")

    #total in cents
    the_total = @order.total.to_f
    the_total_cents = (the_total*100).to_i

    Stripe.api_key = $STRIPE_PREFS['stripe_secret']

    #add order details
    @order.transaction_number = params[:id]

    # Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
    session[:coin_total] = (params[:bitcoin_amount].to_f/100000000).to_s

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :amount => params[:amount],
      :currency => params[:currency],
      :source => params[:id],
      :description => 'Software purchase'
    )

    #re-add completed order details
    the_id = charge["id"]
    @order.transaction_number = the_id
    @order.comment = 'Total = ' + (params[:bitcoin_amount].to_f/100000000).to_s + 'BTC; payment address = ' + params[:inbound_address]

    @order.status = 'C'
    @order.finish_and_save()
    session[:order_id] = @order.id

    #send license
    Thread.new do
      OrderMailer.thankyou(@order).deliver
    end

    #logger.info session.inspect
    render :action => 'thankyou_bitcoin'
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made more revisions, and actually removed all polling logic from my .erb, electing to use a web hook instead.
https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks

```
require 'json'
require 'stripe'

class Store::BitcoinController < ApplicationController

  def payment_recieved
    type = params[:type]
    data = params[:data]

    if (type.blank? || type != "bitcoin.receiver.filled" || data.blank?)
      logger.warn("Got request to Bitcoin IPN with invalid receiver email from #{request.remote_addr || request.remote_ip}")
      render :nothing => true, :status => 200
      return
    end

..process order here...
```

hopefully this will help some others with the same issues.
:)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding the polling logic into the timer, and this seems to work.... although it was implied in the docs that i didn't need to manually poll? at least thats how i read it...

here is my complete amended payment_bitcoin.html.erb for anyone else experiencing issues getting this working

```
<%= render :partial => "offsite_checkout_summary" %>

<p>Your license key, along with your purchase receipt, will be sent to <strong><%= @order.licensee_name %></strong> at <strong><%= @order.email %></strong> once payment has been confirmed.</p>

<div id="extra_purchase_notes">
    <em><strong>Note:</strong> The bitcoin link and price provided is only valid for <span id="countdown_time">10:00</span> minutes.</em>
</div>

<div class="d cl"></div>
<%= render :partial => "items_checkout_summary", :locals => { order: @order } %>
  <div id="bitcoin_payment_address">
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/stripe.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      Stripe.setPublishableKey('<%= $STRIPE_PREFS['stripe_publishable_key'] %>');
      function populateBitcoinCheckout(status, response) {
        if (status === 200) {
          document.getElementById("bitcoin_total").innerHTML = " (" + response.bitcoin_amount/100000000 + " BTC)";
          document.getElementById("bitcoin_payment_string").innerHTML = 'Please send: <strong>' + response.bitcoin_amount/100000000 + ' BTC</strong> to <strong>' + '<a href="' + response.bitcoin_uri + '&label=Software+Purchase">' + response.inbound_address + '</a></strong>';
          document.getElementById("btc-button").href = response.bitcoin_uri + '&label=Software+Purchase';

          //configure timer
          function startTimer(duration, countdown) {
              var timer = duration,minutes,seconds;
              var t = setInterval(function () {

                  minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
                  seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

                  minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
                  seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

                  //poll reciever
                  Stripe.bitcoinReceiver.pollReceiver(response.id, filledReceiverHandler(response));

                  countdown.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

                  if (--timer < 0) {
                      clearInterval(t);
                      document.getElementById("bitcoin_total").innerHTML = "";
                      document.getElementById("bitcoin_payment_string").innerHTML = "";
                      document.getElementById("bitcoin_button_text").innerHTML = "Refresh Order"
                      document.getElementById("btc-button").href = "javascript:history.back()"
                      document.getElementById("extra_purchase_notes").innerHTML = "<em><strong>Oops...</strong> This order has expired, use the Refresh Order button to retry.</em>"
                      Stripe.bitcoinReceiver.cancelReceiverPoll(response.id);
                  }
              }, 1000);
          }

          //start timer
          var countdown = document.getElementById('countdown_time');
          startTimer(600, countdown);

        } else {
          document.getElementById("bitcoin_uri_string").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response);
        }
      }

      Stripe.bitcoinReceiver.createReceiver({
        amount: "<%= (@order.total * 100).round %>",
        currency: 'usd',
        description: 'Software purchase',
        email: "<%= @order.email %>"
      }, populateBitcoinCheckout);

            function filledReceiverHandler(response)
            {
                if (response.filled === true) {
                    function post(path, parameters) {
                var form = $('<form></form>');
                form.attr("method", "post");
                form.attr("action", path);

                $.each(parameters, function(key, value) {
            if ( typeof value == 'object' || typeof value == 'array' ){
                $.each(value, function(subkey, subvalue) {
                    var field = $('<input />');
                    field.attr("type", "hidden");
                    field.attr("name", key+'[]');
                    field.attr("value", subvalue);
                    form.append(field);
                });
            } else {
                var field = $('<input />');
                field.attr("type", "hidden");
                field.attr("name", key);
                field.attr("value", value);
                form.append(field);
            }
            });
            $(document.body).append(form);
            form.submit();
            }
                post('purchase_bitcoin', response);
            }
        }
    </script>
    </div>
</div>
<p id="bitcoin_payment_string"></p>
<div class="d"></div>

<p style="text-align: right;">
  <a id="btc-button"><button class="bitcoin-button" style="visibility: visible;"><span id="bitcoin_button_text">Pay with Bitcoin</span></button></a>
</p>
```